# Keras custom loss function issue when using K.sum()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm having an issue when writing a custom loss function in keras, specifically when I use `K.sum()` inside the loss function. To simplify, let's take the below example:

This works fine:

```
from keras import backend as K

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):        
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_pred - y_true))
```

Now, if I want to normalize `y_pred`, before evaluating the loss above:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = y_pred / K.sum(y_pred, axis=-1)
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_pred - y_true))
```

I'm getting the below error during `model.fit_generator()`

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [64,9] vs. [64]
     [[{{node loss_13/dense_2_loss/truediv}}]]
     [[metrics_9/mean_absolute_error/Mean_1/_5003]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [64,9] vs. [64]
     [[{{node loss_13/dense_2_loss/truediv}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

I've seen many questions regarding the Incompatible shapes error but none seemed to be concerned about the usage of `K.sum()`.

I can notice that 64 is the batch size and 9 is the number of classes I have (both `y_true` and `y_pred` are expected to be (64, 9)).

---

I've added some print statements to see what happens during the `model.compile()` and here are the outputs:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    print(f"Shape of y_pred before normalization: {y_pred.shape}")
    y_pred = y_pred / K.sum(y_pred, axis=-1)
    print(f"Shape of y_pred after normalization: {y_pred.shape}")
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_pred - y_true))
```

Compiling

```
# compile the model
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, metrics=['mae'], optimizer='Adam')

# outputs
# Shape of y_pred before normalization: (?, 9)
# Shape of y_pred after normalization: (?, 9)
```

---

Version Info:

```
keras                     2.2.4                    
keras-applications        1.0.8                   
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0  
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                
tensorflow-gpu            1.14.0
```

Comment: Why not set `keepdim=True` in `K.sum()`?

Comment: @zihaozhihao Oh! That was the issue. I've read the docs but I didn't get the importance of this. Thanks a lot. Could you please add an explanation / answer to accept?

Comment: Hi, I have added the explanation, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @zihaozhihao. Btw, what would you say about the two print statements in my function?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results on my machine. It's invalid to do division with two different shapes. Are you sure that's the output of the code?

Comment: @zihaozhihao I've taken [this example](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/) and replaced the loss with a custom loss in [this colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DTjXEhgA4qsvxUZgi9GCDGrfdP3whmA7). The print outputs show that the tensor shapes are similar to what's shown in the question when compiling.

Comment: Maybe during the compile time, keras didn't check shape match...That is an unexpected behavior I guess.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll update if I've found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, `K.sum(y_pred, axis=-1)` will calculate the sum along the last dim. There is another argument `keepdim` in `K.sum()` which is False in default. So after calculating the sum along the last dim, it will squeeze this dim. Because you want to normalize the `y_pred`, you should keep the last dim (*broadcasting* related).

```py
ef custom_loss_norm(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = y_pred / K.sum(y_pred, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_pred - y_true))
```